# Numpy - Array to Matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am writing a python script where I input a numpy array and return it as a matrix; however, with some of the values changed. Running this code, I get an error saying;

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

I have attached my current function below

```
def w1(X):
    """
    Input:
    - X: A numpy array

    Returns:
    - A matrix Y such that Y[i, j] = X[i, j] * 10 + 100
    """

    Y = np.asmatrix(X)

    for i in Y:
        for j in i:
            Y[i,j] = Y[i,j] * 10 + 100
    return Y
```

Comment: Why not just `(X * 10 + 100).tolist()`

Comment: @Chrispresso because you must use numpy to return a matrix

Comment: Then just do `np.asmatrix(X * 10 + 100)`

Comment: `np.matrix` has a note saying that its use is no longer recommended.  But this kind of iteration would still be a problem with a `numpy` array.  Or a list (of lists).  `for i in ['a','b','c']: print(i)` prints the letters, the elements of the list, not their indices.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
import numpy as np


    def w1(X):
        """
        Input:
        - X: A numpy array
    
        Returns:
        - A matrix Y such that Y[i, j] = X[i, j] * 10 + 100
        """
    
        # Y = np.asmatrix(X)  # you probably won't need this
    
        height, width = X.shape
    
        for i in range(height):
            for j in range(width):
                X[i, j] = X[i, j] * 10 + 100
        return X
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        h, w = 3, 4
        X = np.arange(1, h*w+1).reshape(h, w)
        print(X)
    
        print(w1(X.copy()))
    
        # much faster
        Y = X * 10 + 100
        print(Y)
```

Comment: I actually tried doing Y = np.asmatrix(X * 10 + 100) and returned Y which passed the tests, not sure how it works tho

Comment: @CosmoJohnson You can simplify you function. See my edits. You can also do `Y = X*10 + 100` which is much faster. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @CosmoJohnson Numpy allows you to vectorize operations to speed up computations so you don't have to access each element of your array individually.

Answer (score 1):

The answer written by Samuel is perfect. I'll elaborate on the mistake you made.

The error in your code is in the line

```
for i in Y:
    for j in i:
```

Y is a numpy matrix. Consider it as an array of numpy arrays. So when you write the above code, in each iteration, `i` is a **complete row**. When you write `for j in i`, `j` takes the actual values present in that row of the matrix instead of iterating through the column number of the particular row. That is why you are facing index issues in your method. Hope you got this!